# PowerShell - Start rocopy only if all services have stopped

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I'm new to PowerShell and was wondering if anyone can assist me with the following since I was unable to find any previous thread for this question on the site.

Question: Is there a way to write out a robocopy command so that it will only start if the services in $stopservices have all stopped? Below is what I have but at some points the service is still running when the robocopy starts and then errors out for "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".

```
<## Stop all services ##>
    write-host `r`n "Stopping services on "$server `r`n
    foreach ($service in $stopservices) 
    {
        set-service $service -ComputerName $server -StartupType Disabled -Status Stopped -PassThru
    }


<## Copy all files ##>
    $robocopy = "{0} {1} {2} /XF {3} {4} {5} /XD {6} {7} /MIR /MT /TEE /LOG:{8}" -f $robocopy, $source, $destination, $logPath
    Invoke-Expression $robocopy
    Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the services aren't stopping you could try using the `Stop-Service` Cmdlet after `Set-Service`.

```
 Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server | Stop-Service -Force
```

Then you could wait for the services to stop by using the following while loop just before the `Robocopy`.

```
While($stopservices | Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running" -or $_.Status -eq "Stopping"}){
    Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

This will sleep the script for 5 seconds if 1 of the services in `$stopservices` are still running. Once all services do not have a `Running` or `Stopping` status the `Robocopy` will start. So the whole script might look something like this:

```
# Stop all services #
write-host `r`n "Stopping services on "$server `r`n
foreach ($service in $stopservices) 
{
    set-service $service -ComputerName $server -StartupType Disabled -Status Stopped -PassThru
    Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server | Stop-Service -Force 

}

While($stopservices | Get-Service | ? {$_.Status -eq "Running" -or $_.Status -eq "Stopping"}){
    Sleep -Seconds 5
}

# Copy all files #
$robocopy = "{0} {1} {2} /XF {3} {4} {5} /XD {6} {7} /MIR /MT /TEE /LOG:{8}" -f $robocopy, $source, $destination, $logPath
Invoke-Expression $robocopy
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks Richard! This is great. I tried it without the Stop-Service Cmdlet but added the while loop. For some reason after the 5 second period it doesn't appear that it's looping back to try to stop the other service that's still running in $stopservices.